# Rally C#: How can I query for the number of attachments that were uploaded to a user story in Rally?

Tags: c#, web-services, rally

I am trying to get the number of attachments for a given user story in Rally.
How can I accomplish that in programmatically.

```
public void getAttachmentCount(string workspaceRef, string projectRef)
{
 //Authenticate
 this.EnsureRallyIsAuthenticated();

 //setup the userStoryRequest
 Request userStoryRequest = new Request("Attachments");
 userStoryRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
 userStoryRequest.Project = projectRef;

 //fetch data from the story request
 userStoryRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
 {
     "Attachments"
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the Attachment count for a specific User Story found by using the FormattedID.

```
Request userStoryRequest = new Request("HierarchicalRequirement");
userStoryRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
userStoryRequest.Project = projectRef;
userStoryRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "US1");
userStoryRequest.Fetch = new List<string>(){"Attachments"};

QueryResult userStoryResult = restApi.Query(userStoryRequest);
foreach(var result in userStoryResult.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attachment Count: " + result["Attachments"].Count);
}
```

You would also need to pass in or know the FormattedID for the User Story (Hierarchical Requirement) in question.